# Upgraded to Magento 2.4.6 in Staging Env but Prod Still 2.4.4 - Can I Still Import 2.4.4 DB over top?

Tags: magento2, migration

My prod is 2.4.4
I've moved servers and migrated my prod env.
But I had to upgrade to 2.4.6 on the new server - which I did successfully.

Now my old prod db is still based on 2.4.4, but I need to move the old db to the new server which is 2.4.6

My question - can I just export the 2.4.4 db, then import it over the top of the 2.4.6 db?
Maybe then run the setup command again?

Or do I have to do the whole migration again, ie: files, db, composer require, setup, etc. etc.

Or is there another way?

Basically, I'm not sure if when I upgraded to 2.4.6 if the upgrade made changes in the db which won't be captured if I just put the prod 2.4.4 db on top of the 2.4.6 files.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with just creating a new database, import the 2.4.4 data and change the `etc.php` configuration to the new one. Run `setup:upgrade` and put it in production mode :)

The `setup:upgrade` will handle all the database migration work for you